# How to write Nested PHP Array in Java android

Tags: java, php, android

Please how would I write a PHP array like this in Java for Android? Its meant to be sent as a server request

```
<?php
require_once('./lib/Start.php');
Start::ApiKey("test_sec_k_1629dbd087def5325d294");

Start_Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "payment for" => "housing",
  "company" => array(
    "name" => "John Smith",
    "address" => "address1",
    "id" => 111,

  ),
  "description" => "Two widgets (test@example.com)",
  "email" => "joe@example.com"
));
?>
```

Comment: Veetweezy, you should explain better what you mean. You want to post from an Android to a site running php? You could try to encode as json. And you decode in your php script.

Comment: Hi @otaviofcs, yes, I need to post this to a server running PHP from Android. I want to write thesame PHP nested array as BasicNameValuePairs in Android